How to Send FCM Notifications with cURL
I'm having trouble sending an FCM notification using this cURL command:

curl --location 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/clash-of-zombies-c2d15/messages:send' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer $token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
        "message": {
          "token": "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
          "notification": {
            "title": "Hello",
            "body": "World"
          }
        }
      }'

However, I'm getting an error message:
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
        "status": "NOT_FOUND",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
                "errorCode": "UNREGISTERED"
            }
        ]
    }
}

What's the Problem?
i know that my token is valid
